# How to convert a single column containing multiple rows into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a column , says name Student_name and its values lets say, A, B, C, D, E, F and so on..

Now i have to convert this column into row with each alias.

```
select A.counts from (
select count(b.ATTND_FLAG) as counts , b.ATTND_FLAG as ATTND_FLAG
from hr_emp_notifications a, v_emp_attendance b
where a.emp_id=b.emp_id
and a.emp_id=90327
and b.ATTND_FLAG is not null
group by b.ATTND_FLAG )A
```

my query showing one column which has multiple values in rows.
i have to convert these values into row.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would really help your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
       sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_b,
       sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as num_c,
       sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as num_d,
       sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as num_e,
       sum(case when ea.attnd_flag = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as num_f
from v_emp_attendance ea
where ea.emp_id = 90327;
```

If you want multiple employees, use `group by`ea.emp_id`.

Notice that the `join` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a pivot clause here -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT NAME, ATTND_FLAG
      FROM v_emp_attendance)
PIVOT (COUNT(ATTND_FLAG)
       FOR NAME IN ('A' AS A, 'B' AS B, 'C' AS C /* AND SO ON */)
      )
```